# Paperclip sets incorrect content_type and file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a photo attachment with several styles all of which convert the image to a jpg, e.g.:

```
styles: { original: { geometry: "1500x1500>", format: :jpg},
          large:  { geometry: "1000x1000>", format: :jpg } }
```

The model also has a `before_post_process` that renames photo's filename to a standard name:

```
def rename_photo
    extension = File.extname(photo_file_name).downcase
    self.photo.instance_write :file_name, "original#{extension}"
end
```

This works fine: whatever I upload is converted and uploaded to AWS S3 as a `JPG`.
However, if the image is a `PNG` its file_name and content_type are stored in db as `original.png` and `image/png` accordingly, while on S3 it is stored as a `JPG`. When I query photo's url, a correct `JPG` url is returned as well.

So while everything works, it bothers me that incorrect information is stored in the db.

Comment: If the original is a PNG, isn't it correct to store the original filename as `original.png`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jon, I'd like to convert all of the uploaded pictures to JPG. Paperclip converts everything perfectly, but stores `photo_file_name` as `original.png` and `photo_content_type` as `image/png` in the database even though the file has now been converted to a `JPG`. Interestingly, when I query photo's url, it correctly returns url to a `JPG` file.

Comment: Paperclip also stores an unmodified copy of the originally uploaded file, which I suspect is still a png. Therefore, the original filename is correct. If you **REALLY** want the original to not be saved in it's *ORIGINAL* format, you need to define a style for `:original` in your 'styles' hash. Beware though - if you ever wanted to reprocess all your attachments because you've added a new style, you WILL NOT have the original any more to do this from.

Comment: @Jon, as you can see from the code I posted, I have already defined a style for the `:original`, and according to that code, the original should be converted to a `jpg`. The original in fact gets converted and stored as a `jpg`, but the information in the database says it's still a `png`. Hence the question.

Comment: Well, I know it's not what you asked for, but personally I'd be happier with the "original" filename being original. If you need a style with that format and geometry, then just create an `uploaded` style or something and use that instead. It certainly feels wrong to have something which you've modified and call it 'original'.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on older rails 2.3 code and had to upgraded Paperclip from 2.3.1.1 to 2.7.5 and I have this same issue. Everything worked beautifully for years in 2.3.1.1. I have one style that resizes and converts to png. In 2.3.1.1, regardless of the extension on the original file (jpg, gif, png) Paperclip would save my styled image file as png, as I requested. When I asked for the url for my converted image the file's extension in the url was properly set as png. All of this regardless of the extension of the original image.

In Paperclip 2.7.5, my untouched has_attached_file options saves the styled image file with the same extension as the original file and the request for the url to the styled image file also returns with the extension set the same as the original file.

I observed the ImageMagick convert command that was invoked by paperclip to create the styled image and it properly refers to a png file for conversion and output. I also viewed the contents of the styled image in hex and it is formatted as a png file (original was a jpg). So it seems that the conversion is working by Paperclip is not giving the styled image the extension of png, like it used to.

```
has_attached_file :image,
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => Application.s3_credentials,
  :s3_protocol    => 'https',
  :path => "home_pages/:id/images/:basename-:style.:extension",
  :default_style => '450',
  :styles => { '450' => ['450x253>', :png] }
```

Unfortunately I cannot spend resources at this time to rewrite our app for Rails 4 so I am stuck here in  the twilight zone. The reason I had to upgrade to the last version of paperclip that is supposed to work with Rails 2.3 is so I could upgrade the aws-sdk gem in order to use some new features of Amazon AWS.

Has anyone experienced this and maybe figured out a soulution?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the source code for PaperClip 2.7.5, I came up with this solution that is working for me. Add this to config/initializers/paperclip.rb in your app.

```
# In Paperclip 2.3.1.1 to 2.7.5 (maybe more) the extension method fails to
# return the extension of an attachment with a style that has a 'format'.
module Paperclip
  module Interpolations
    def extension attachment, style_name
      style = attachment.styles[style_name.to_s] || attachment.styles[style_name.to_s.to_sym]
      style && style[:format] ? style[:format].to_s : File.extname(attachment.original_filename).gsub(/^\.+/, '')
    end
  end
```